# Make a data profiler class that takes as params on the init a list of data

Tags: python, list, class, init, self

I need this class to include the following methods only using **self**:

1. get_summary_stats: should calculate the mean, min and max.
2. min_max_scale: converts the array to 0-1 values.
3. score_scale: converts the array to zscores.

I'm trying it this way without luck, when you run it it smoothly goes by but when I add the last line it gives me an error saying  `__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

```
class summary_stats_class():
    
    def __init__(self):
        min_my_list  = min(self)
        max_my_list  = max(self)
        mean_my_list = sum(self)/len(self)
        std_my_list = np.std(self)
    def get_summary_stats(self):
        print(min_my_list,max_my_list,mean_my_list)
        
    def min_max_scale(self):
        print((i - min_my_list) / (max_my_list-mean_my_list) for i in self)
    
    def zscore_scale(self):
        print((i - mean_my_list) / std_my_list for i in self)
summary_stats_class([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
```

I've tried
1)adding *list* to summary_stats_class(*list*) because I read it in other question, as well as
2)adding `self.list = []` after `__init__` piece and finally
3) adding , *args, **kwargs to each method without any luck, could someone please help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `self` is used to indicate the class level variables. The [documentation on classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables) has some examples showing how to use the `self` to declare instance variables and use them in class methods.

I have updated the class to mitigate the error:

```
import numpy as np


class summary_stats_class():

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.min_data = min(data)
        self.max_data = max(data)
        self.mean_data = sum(data) / len(data)
        self.std_data = np.std(data)

    def get_summary_stats(self):
        return self.min_data, self.max_data, self.mean_data

    def min_max_scale(self):
        return [(i - self.min_data) / (self.max_data - self.min_data) for i in
                self.data]

    def zscore_scale(self):
        return [(i - self.mean_data) / self.std_data for i in self.data]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ssc = summary_stats_class([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
    print(ssc.get_summary_stats())
    print(ssc.min_max_scale())
    print(ssc.zscore_scale())
```

**Output:**

```
(1, 10, 5.5)
[0.0, 0.1111111111111111, 0.2222222222222222, 0.3333333333333333, 0.4444444444444444, 0.5555555555555556, 0.6666666666666666, 0.7777777777777778, 0.8888888888888888, 1.0]
[-1.5666989036012806, -1.2185435916898848, -0.8703882797784892, -0.5222329678670935, -0.17407765595569785, 0.17407765595569785, 0.5222329678670935, 0.8703882797784892, 1.2185435916898848, 1.5666989036012806]
```

**Explanation:**

- We passed the list as a parameter when we created the `ssc` object of the class `summary_stats_class`.
- In the constructor of `summary_stats_class`, we set the parameter list to `self.data` variable.
- We then calculated the min, max, and mean of the data and set them to `self.min_data`, `self.max_data`, and `self.mean_data` respectively. We set them to `self` so that these variables can be used from any other methods of the class.
- In the `get_summary_stats`, `min_max_scale`, and `zscore_scale` method, we used the previously calculated variables using `self.VARIABLE_NAME`.

**References:**

- [Documentation on classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables)
- [Z-score normalization](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for such a didactive and valuable answer!